# How to remove variables from a dataset that are actually named NA?

Tags: r, excel, dataset

I have an excel dataset that I have to work on. The problem is that empty cells were named NA instead of leaving them empty.

I'm trying to remove NA values from the dataset and usually I could use `is.na()` to omit them but now they have a name so I don't know how to go about this.

Any ideas to point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like below:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% mutate(across(everything(), ~ na_if(., 'NA'))) %>% na.omit()
# A tibble: 3 x 2
  Drinks ranked
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 A      1     
2 C      2     
3 C      1
```

Data used:

```
df
# A tibble: 5 x 2
  Drinks ranked
  <chr>  <chr> 
1 A      1     
2 B      NA    
3 NA     1     
4 C      2     
5 C      1
```